# Add a custom shortcut to IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I add a custom key shortcut (ie: ctrl-something) in IntelliJ / Android Studio, so that it will automatically add a custom snippet that I associated to that combination? Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a live template `settings>Editor>Live Templates`.

Choose your category, and click on the "**+**" sign. You can then choose the abbreviation, add variable using the `$VARIABLE$` notation and the context (Java, XML etc..).

Now you can just type the abbreviation in the editor and auto-complete it (ctrl+space, tab) and your snippet will be written.